# Excel combo box not merging entries from two columns but listing them as two seperate entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have drop down requires information to be pulled out from two columns on the lookupDept workbook and merged. For instance I have:

```
deptCode deptName
BS       Business School
CD       Design and Technology
CG       Chemical Engineering
CM       Chemistry
CO       Computer Science
```

I've managed to sort out my problem regarding information being pulled out from two spead-sheet columns to be used in a combo box. But unfortunately the combo-box list now looks like this:

```
BS
CD
CG
CM
Business School
Design and Technology
Chemical Engineering
Chemistry
```

when I would like it to look like this:

```
BS Business School
CD Design and Technology
CG Chemical Engineering
CM Chemistry
```

This requires two columns of information to be merged (columns have been named *deptCode* and *deptName*) but I'm not too sure how to accomplish it. Here is what I've tried so far, the code listing information from both columns rather than merging them:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim c_deptCode As Range
Dim c_deptName As Range
Dim ws_dept As Worksheet
Set ws_dept = Worksheets("lookupDept")

For Each c_deptCode In ws_dept.Range("deptCode")
  With Me.cbo_deptCode
    .AddItem c_deptCode.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_deptCode.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next c_deptCode

For Each c_deptName In ws_dept.Range("deptName")
  With Me.cbo_deptCode
    .AddItem c_deptName.Value
  End With
Next c_deptName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ColumnCount` property of the combo box to `2`, and load your data into the `List` property as a two dimensional array

You can also set the column widths to suit using `ColumnWidths`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim c_deptCode As Range
    Dim c_deptName As Range
    Dim ws_dept As Worksheet

    Dim aDat() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws_dept = Worksheets("lookupDept")
    Set c_deptCode = ws_dept.Range("deptCode")
    Set c_deptName = ws_dept.Range("deptName")
    aDat = c_deptCode
    ReDim Preserve aDat(1 To UBound(aDat, 1), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(aDat, 1)
        aDat(i, 2) = c_deptName.Cells(i, 1)
    Next
    With cbo_deptCode
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "20;50"
        .List = aDat
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the main issue is that you are adding the second range completely separate from the first (and I know that is your question, so I'll apologize for pointing out the obvious :) ). In any case, what you could do is something like the below - basically combine the values from the two ranges and then add that single value to the drop-down. The main changes were adding two new variables (that represent arrays containing the values of your named ranges) and condensing the `For` loops into one.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim c_deptCode As Range
Dim c_deptName As Range
Dim deptCodes As Variant
Dim deptNames As Variant

Dim ws_dept As Worksheet
Set ws_dept = Worksheets("lookupDept")

' Assign each range to an array containing the values
deptCodes = Choose(1, ws_dept.Range("deptCode"))
deptNames = Choose(1, ws_dept.Range("deptName"))

' Note that this blindly uses deptCode as a sort of control.
' This could be handled a bit better, but should work for this case
For i = 1 To ws_dept.Range("deptCode").Rows.Count
  ' Create the combined name (code + space + name)
  CombinedName = deptCodes(i, 1) & " " & deptNames(i, 1)
  cbo_deptCode.AddItem CombinedName
Next i

End Sub
```